# wamp - notice undefined offset

Tags: php, wamp

How to turn off this error in wamp:

> notice undefined offset

I'd like to turn of just this error, but not all errors.

Comment: Write correct code?

Comment: I always treat notices like errors, but to say the code is not correct without providing any other insight is not helpful.

Comment: @Mike Sherov: I don't necessarily assume that the OP's code is incorrect. With this statement I wanted to express that dealing with the **cause** of the effect (displaying the message) is better than dealing with the effect itself. And yes the statement was meant to be provocative .

Comment: @Felix, I knew what you were getting at. Of course, correct errors instead of hiding them! But at least you could convey that concept to the OP in more than 3 words.

Comment: @Mike Sherov, that is why I gave a (hopefully more) useful answer....

Comment: @Felix, I see it now. :-) Just trying to raise the level of discourse here a bit. I guess I shouldn't judge. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike, Considering the post, I think a three word response is very appropriate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues at work here. One is what errors PHP reports, and the second is whether or not it displays those errors on the page (as opposed to the apache error log). If you'd like to turn off just NOTICES:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

If you'd like to report the notices to your error log but not display them to the user, do this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','off');
?>
```

Note that turning off display errors will stop displaying ALL errors to the end user, and you'll need to look at the error log, usually located in /var/log/httpd/error_log to see any errors while testing.

Comment: Also wamp has a setting that turns the settings on by default now. It's under php settings -> display errors. I wrote a small blog on it because the internet wasn't helping: http://www.kanersan.com/blog.php?blogId=45

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`error_reporting()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

You could e.g. set the error reporting to

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE)
```

But better would be to actually check what is the cause of the `Notice` and fix it. Then you are on the save side.

> `E_NOTICE`
>   Run-time notices. Indicate that the script encountered something that could indicate an error, but could also happen in the normal course of running a script.

Answer (score 3):

(If you can't fix the code...) You can exclude notices by setting an reporting level `x & ~E_NOTICE`, e.g.

```
<?php error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
```

or in your php.ini (or similar)

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Answer (score 0):

php.ini => error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Answer (score 0):

error->notice undefined offset

main thing is remove the error on your script.Programmer always wish to design program which is error free instead of error hiding.

The array vales are not set, so when PHP is trying to access the value of those array keys it encounters an undefined offset.

```
$new_array = array('1','2','3');//If I have an array
//We can now access:
$new_array[0];
$new_Array[1];
$new_array[2];
//If we try and access
$new_Array[3];
```

we will get the same error-->error->notice undefined offset

Answer (score 0):

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 ini_set('html_errors', 'Off');
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

Go to This direction on windows OS C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin
Then open php.ini file by any editor recommended [sublime] in 514 line just paste this two lines.

;error_reporting = E_ALL  
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE